# How to fix BufferReader issue in java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

Its been a while since I did Java and so am going through a book. As far as I can see the following code is correct however I am having trouble compiling it. I used to use `Scanner`, but this book is taking this approach, and I would prefer to follow it and do the exercises as explained, can anyone see what is wrong here?

```
import java.io.*;

class ReadFile
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{

  try
  {
    FileReader file = new FileReader("Sheffield.data");
  }

  catch (IOException e)
  {
    System.out.println("A read error has ocurred" );
  }

  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
  String line = "";

  while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
  {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  buffer.close();

}
}
```

The error I am getting in Windows cmd is as follows:
[image]

Simple error I know, any help will be much appreciated.

FIXED!!

```
  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
  String line = "";

  while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
  {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  buffer.close();
```

the above should all  be placed in the `try` statement under the `FileReader file = new FileReader("Sheffield.data");`

Comment: Variable scope. The name `file` is only usable within the `try` block.

Comment: This question has been updated and answered I guessed that was the issue. The book indicated to do the `BufferReader` statement outside the `try`, however the latter code block needed moving inside. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`file` variable is created in the try block and thus `BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);` doesnt have access to it. Create the reference before try and instantiate in th try block.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I figured however its how this book says to do it, Mike McGrath - Java in Easy Steps 4th edition.